# How to get a bash script argument given its position from the end?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I've got a shell script and I want to use the last argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo My last param is #somehow put it here
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
echo $$#
echo ${$#}
echo ${(($#))}
```

Unfortunately it did not work.

I'm specifically want to understand why my options did not work, I want to do something like double expansion.

In a broader sense, I would like to know how to access the Nth argument from the end. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is your question for a solution specific to **bash**?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition (to Kusalananda's answer):

```
#! /bin/bash 

echo "(bash/ksh): ${@: -1}"
echo "(bash 3.x+): ${!#}"
echo "(bash 3.x+): $BASH_ARGV"
echo "(bash 3.x+/ksh): ${@:$#}"
echo "(bash 3.x+): ${BASH_ARGV[0]}"
```

and if you worry about portability:

```
#!/bin/bash

penultimate=''
ultimate=''

for p in "$@" ; do
    penultimate="$ultimate"
    ultimate="$p"
done

echo "penultimate=$penultimate"
echo "ultimate=$ultimate"
```

Comment: to Kusalananda's answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right; I added it in the answer.

Comment: can you please explain about this notation? ${!#}

Comment: @YardenST From the bash manpage: "If the first character of parameter is an exclamation  point  (!),  and parameter  is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash uses the value of the variable  formed  from  the  rest  of parameter  as  the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value  of  parameter  itself.  This is known as indirect expansion."

Comment: @YardenST In other words, bash takes `#`, expands it like it would `$#`, and then the result (let's say `5`) is put through variable expansion again like it would `$5`.

Comment: From the manual *The shell sets BASH_ARGV only when in extended debugging mode*. So, that parameter is not always present.

Comment: The `${@:$#}` works on bash (since at least 2.01), ksh and zsh.

Comment: @JoL awesome, this is exactly the thing i was trying to workout!

Comment: @YardenST Yes. Honestly, I think your attempts show what would have been the most obvious, intuitive syntax. I can only imagine `${!x}` was chosen to intentionally limit the syntax to only allow 1 level of indirection instead of multiple by nesting, maybe to ease the implementation. There's probably other subtle reasons, though, like arguments about consistency and how it implies that other thing could also be nested.

Answer (score 5):

To get any argument from `bash` script, you can use slicing:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get 3rd element from the end
from_end1=3
# Get last element
from_end2=1

# Get slice of array [end - from_end1 : end ] of length 1
echo "${@: -$from_end1: 1}"
echo "${@: -$from_end2: 1}"
```

You can also use this to get Nth element:

```
# Get 2nd element
from_beginning=2

echo "${@: $from_beginning: 1}"
```

Remember to check for length; this might return your program's name or an empty string.

Comment: This is bash-specific, right? You should probably note that since the OP's question did not mention bash except in the `#!` (and in particular didn't use bash tag).

Comment: @R.. Fair point, information added.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` (release 4.3+), you may assign the passed parameters to an array and access the last one by the index `-1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

params=( "$@" )
printf 'The last parameter given to the script is %s\n' "${params[-1]}"

foo () {
    params=( "$@" )
    printf 'The last parameter given to the function is %s\n' "${params[-1]}"
}
```

In general, negative indexes into arrays accesses the elements from the end of the array.

Comment: A negative index might work on bash 4.2+ depending on the patch level. But an slice `${@: -1:1}` works with negative indexes since bash 3.0.

Comment: @Isaac That's good if you are code golfing, but not if you're writing code that others need to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Portable `sh`, not bash-specific, and without O(n) loops:

```
eval x=\$$(($#-1))
```

The `-1` yields the penultimate argument; replace it with the position you want relative to the end, or drop it entirely if you want the very last one.

Comment: One of the very few uses of `eval` I've ever seen that actually seems merited and safe.

Answer (score 1):

The clasic solutions for POSIX shells (which also work on ksh, zsh or bash) are:

```
 for last do :;done; echo "last=$last"
 eval "last=\$$#"; echo "last=$last"
```

For newer shells (ksh93,zsh,bash):

```
 echo "last=${@: -1}"
 echo "last=${@:(-1)}"
 echo "last=${@:~0}"
 echo "last=${@:$#}"
```

Only for:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `echo "last=${!#}"`
 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `echo "last=$BASH_ARGV"`
 [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) `echo "last=${@[-1]}"`
 [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) `echo "last=${@[#]}"`

For the penultimate argument:

```
 for arg do penultimate=$ultimate; ultimate=$arg; done; echo "$penultimate"
 eval penultimate=\$$((#-1))
 echo "${@:$((#-1)):1}"
 echo "${@: -2:1}"
 echo "${@:~1:1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, the most natural thing, I think, would be:

```
echo "ultimate: ${@[$#]}"
echo "ultimate: ${@[-1]}"
echo "penultimate: ${@[-2]}"
echo "penultimate: ${@[$(($# - 1))]}"
```